# How to forward local port 80 to another machine?

Tags: ssh

I want to port 127:0.0.1:80 to the other machine via SSH, how can I do that? I tried adding -R 8000:localhost:80, but it doesn't work. By the way, PHP is also installed on localhost, maybe that's why?

Answer (score 6):

Only root can bind ports numbered under 1024.

The cleanest way is just to use local port 8000:

```
ssh -R 8000:localhost:8000 otherhost
```

Alternatively,

```
sudo ssh -R 8000:localhost:80 me@otherhost
```

(It's really better not to run this as root for the sake of security - just use another port.)

If you must use root, and you're using ssh private-key authentication, you may need to tell it which identity file to use. For example

```
sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa -R 8000:localhost:80 me@otherhost
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to do that via sudo, I get Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the identity file. Try also using `ssh -v`.

Comment: Thanks again, I logged it via sudo successfully, but it doesn't work... I just see 404 not found on 127.0.0.1:80...

Comment: That's probably a different issue, perhaps connected to your server expecting to see a different virtual host name. Have a look in the server logs.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from what you've just said in chat, this will let you access the server's port 80, from localhost:8080 (you'd need to run this as root to get it on localhost:80, which I don't advise if you can avoid it).

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 host
```