# Is Ubuntu Server 13.10 suitable for running a web server on older hardware?

Tags: 13.10

Will a old computer with 1024M of RAM and a Pentium 4 CPU be able to host a personal website, while still allowing me to use the web browser? Does someone have any recommendations for helping it run more responsively?

Comment: It will probably work, but might not be as fast as you want it to be. Fool-proof way to find out is to try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Potentially.  With only 1GB of RAM given it's going to have a graphical interface, using a web browser (which are quite memory-heavy nowadays), the experience may be lackluster.

I would suggest using a lightweight desktop environment instead of Ubuntu's default Unity, such as Xfce or LXDE.  You can install one of these from the command line on Ubuntu Server using `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`.  That way, your desktop/web browsing experience leaves as much RAM as possible aside for the web server to use.

Answer (score 0):

Running a web server with this configuration is possible just use add classic gnome environment  by following these simple steps:

- open the terminal window.
- sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
- Now logout and change the default unity environment to gnome with the option above(left) the username bar.

Personally I have the same configuration and its working good classic-gnome.

Comment: Actually he wants to use web browser bro. Read the post again.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations:

- Don't use the server to do anything else than hosting the website (don't install any desktop enviroment, a server is a server)
- Don't use ubuntu on servers, especially on servers like your server, go for Debian instead.
- Don't install Apache, use Nginx instead.

If you really need to install a web browser, then download [one of these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29540/browsing-the-internet-from-the-command-line), no desktop environment needed. If you really want a GUI experience then go for Openbox