# Is there a way to access AskUbuntu for seeing questions and their related answers through Linux terminal

Tags: command-line, browser

I wish to access AskUbuntu in the terminal for seeing questions and their related answers.

**My use case is this:**

AskUbuntu is an excellent source of learning Linux. But I will have to continuously shift between my browser and terminal every time for seeing the site and learning by typing commands in terminal.

So I wish to atleast browse through the questions and the associated answers from the terminal (My requirement is not to post a new question in AskUbuntu from the terminal, so I don't even require to be signed in). In this way, I can see and type in the terminal itself.

Is it possible?

Comment: Install a command line browser such as [`lynx`](http://lynx.browser.org/).

Comment: @Jos. Ok. Thanks for that.

Comment: Terminal browsers are still browsers that run inside your terminal. You run it like any other program, by typing the program name in the terminal, then open askubuntu.com, then search, then close the browser and continue in the terminal.
In most terminal windows, you can open tabs so you don't have to close the browser to continue, but you still have to switch between the tabs.
I recommend you to get used to switch between your browser and your terminal. The fastest way to switch between windows is `Alt`+ `Tab`

Comment: @Turtle10000 Thanks for that sweet message. Yes `Alt` + `Tab` is a great key. Aware of it. One more reason for not opening the browser is to avoid all the social media messages and the AI-based recommendations. It takes our time away.

Answer (score 2):

I use `lynx` a terminal based web browser.

`sudo apt-get install lynx`

for detail of other terminal based web browsers refer this link:
[Browsing the internet from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29540/browsing-the-internet-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

There is a terminalbased browser: **elinks**. The design is not very easy, but it works.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give a case example for AskUbuntu? That will make things more clear.